# Read a particular line from a CSV with headers in Haskell

Tags: csv, haskell, dataframe

I'm just learning haskell, and trying to make a simple program that gives me a list of tuples of

```
(header, data)
```

when reading a CSV.  I'm trying to use `Data.Text.Lazy` and `Data.Text.Lazio.IO` because I understand
these have good performance and unicode coverage versus `String`.

The function I'm working on will take a line number (`n`) and a CSV filename (`filename`) and return just the `(header, datum)` tuple

Here's my CSV, "dat.csv"

```
ORDINAL,CATEGORICAL,BOOL,CONTINUOUS,INT
Low,Blue,True,1.2,2
Medium,Green,False,0.5,3
High, Green,False,1.0,5
```

Here's my code:

```
-- hs_reader.hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I
import Control.Applicative

getL :: Int -> FilePath -> IO [(Text,Text)]
getL n filename =
  do
    flines <- T.lines <$> I.readFile filename
    let headers = Prelude.head flines
    let body = Prelude.tail flines
    let row = Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) (splitOn "," (body !! n))
    return row
```

And this works like I want kinda:

```
Prelude> :l hs_reader
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hs_reader.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Prelude> getL 1 "dat.csv"
[("ORDINAL","Medium"),("CATEGORICAL","Green"),("BOOL","False"),("CONTINUOUS","0.5"),("INT","3")]
Prelude> getL 2 "dat.csv"
[("ORDINAL","High"),("CATEGORICAL"," Green"),("BOOL","False"),("CONTINUOUS","1.0"),("INT","5")]
```

I realize there's a lot I don't understand about how to use monads correctly.  I have 4 main questions:

Question (1) I'd like to do a partial function application of this to a range of line numbers. Why doesn't this work?

```
let readF x = getL x "dat.csv"
-- a
Prelude.map readF [1..3]
--
Prelude> Prelude.map readF [1..3]
--
<interactive>:514:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO [(Text, Text)]))
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
--
-- b.
Prelude> T.map readF [1..3]
--
<interactive>:515:7:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO [(Text, Text)]’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: Char -> Char
      Actual type: Int -> IO [(Text, Text)]
    In the first argument of ‘T.map’, namely ‘readF’
    In the expression: T.map readF [1 .. 3]
--
<interactive>:515:13:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    In the second argument of ‘T.map’, namely ‘[1 .. 3]’
    In the expression: T.map readF [1 .. 3]
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = T.map readF [1 .. 3]
```

Question (2) Is there a more elegant way to do this? Can I do this without any let statements for example, since I have a do?

Question (3) I tried to use the following because it looked more like examples I had seen online. Why doesn't this work? (I can't use "<-" inside where?)

```
getL2 :: Int -> FilePath ->  [(Text,Text)]
getL2 n filename = do
  Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) (splitOn "," (body !! n))
  where 
    headers = Prelude.head flines
    body = Prelude.tail flines
    flines <- T.lines <$> I.readFile filename
--
-- ERROR!
hs_reader.hs:25:12:
    parse error on input ‘<-’
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Question (4) I'm working with some monads.  Is one of these dudes applicable in an easy way to understand? >>= or >=> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) gets you an [IO [(Text, Text)]], since you mapped an Int -> IO [(Text, Text)] over an [Int]. You want mapM.

(2) !! is a smell. I would have getL make a whole list immediately, and if you really want to supply Ints afterwards you can still use !! at the call site:

```
readCSV :: FilePath -> IO [[(Text,Text)]]
readCSV filename = do
  headers : body <- T.lines <$> I.readFile filename
  return $ map (Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) . splitOn ",") body
```

(3) `flines <- T.lines <$> I.readFile filename` is a monadic bind and you can't just do that in a where clause, the only reason you can do it in a do block is because those are desugared to `>>=`.

(4) Here's how it would look like desugared:

```
readCSV :: FilePath -> IO [[(Text,Text)]]
readCSV filename =
  (T.lines <$> I.readFile filename) >>= \(headers : body) ->
  return $ map (Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) . splitOn ",") body
```

Since filename is used only once at the end of the first line, this could, in fact, be written using `>=>`:

```
readCSV :: FilePath -> IO [[(Text,Text)]]
readCSV =
  fmap T.lines . I.readFile >=> \(headers : body) ->
  return $ map (Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) . splitOn ",") body
```

Since only return is used in the last line, we don't even need `>=>` - `fmap` is enough.

```
readCSV :: FilePath -> IO [[(Text,Text)]]
readCSV =
  fmap ( (\(headers : body) -> map (Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) . splitOn ",") body)
         . T.lines)
  . I.readFile
```

Which of these is more readable, of course, is another question entirely.

Edit: The last one suggests a further refactoring:

```
parseCSV :: Text -> [[(Text, Text)]]
parseCSV = 
  (\(headers : body) -> map (Prelude.zip (splitOn "," headers) . splitOn ",") body)
  . T.lines
```

And then you use it like, for example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  [filename, field] <- getArgs
  csv <- parseCSV <$> I.readFile filename
  print $ traverse (lookup field) csv
```